# Using "OR" within an "IF" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Sorry this is a really simple question, but i just cant figure it. Im attempting to use nested IF statements with an OR condition inside.
This is the code:

```
if (positionE != -1){
   if (position == -1) || if (positionE < position)
                   position = positionE;
}
```

Obviously Im using the OR conditon incorrectly, please could someone point out the correct use.

This is the psuedo-code Im trying to code:

```
If positionE is not -1  
   If position is -1 or positionE is less than position  
      position is positionE
```

Comment: `if(positionE != -1 && (position == -1 || positionE < position))`

Comment: You pseudocode is correct, write it exactly like the pseudo code!

Comment: If (A or B) is what you want, but your code says If (A) or If (B)

Comment: Understand that an `if` statement has as it's argument a mathematical expression.  That expression is evaluated like any other mathematical expression, and the `||` and `&&` operators are (with a slight twist) evaluated the same, conceptually, as `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`.  In fact, the AND operation is sometimes referred to as Boolean multiplication and the OR operation as Boolean addition.  The expression containing the `||` and `&&` operators go *inside* the `if` statement argument, not between `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
if(positionE != -1 && (position == -1 || positionE < position)){
   position = positionE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
if (position == -1 || positionE < position)
               position = positionE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
       if (positionE != -1){
       if (position == -1 || positionE < position)
               position = positionE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your ifs clean, it is not just good practice, it is pretty important for future refactors or modifications.
 - Always use {} for if statements
 - Don't nest ifs if it is not necessary.
 - Use () for separation between && and || to improve the readability.
 - If the structure gets complicated, write it down first on paper, or think about separation of statements, maybe you can merge something.
 - Furthermore I recommend some studies on formal logic.

ideally an if should look like something like this:

```
if( (A && B) || (C && D) ){
 ... do something
}
```

or

```
if( (A || B) && (C || D) ){
 ... do something
}
```

if you make it clean and nice, it will pay back the effort later if you have to change something.
If I understood you well, your case can be described as

```
if( !A && (B || C)){
... do something
}
```

Comment: We dont't see any answer here. It looks like note on "How to use If condition" from some basic Programming book.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (positionE != -1){
   if (position == -1) || if (positionE < position)
                   position = positionE;
}
```

accoring to these we can write the condition as below

```
if(positionE != -1 && positionE < position) {
 position = positionE;
}
```

here we're nullifying the `positionE == -1` condition because code will hit inner condition if and only if `positionE != -1`

Answer (score -3):

Use this:

```
if (positionE!=-1) {
    if ((position==-1) || (positionE<position)) {
         position = positionE;
    }        
}
```